# How do I get a count of how many times a certain number is inside of a json file using php?

Tags: php, json, discord

Here is what my data.json file consists of:

```
[
    {
       "roles":[
          "848173029280055326"
       ],
       "nick":null,
       "avatar":null,
       "premium_since":null,
       "joined_at":"2021-05-29T12:15:32.907000+00:00",
       "is_pending":false,
       "pending":false,
       "user":{
          "id":"848088079562571797",
          "username":"E. Gadd",
          "avatar":"9992dc24217be555eae9dfe1c9960b0e",
          "discriminator":"6174",
          "public_flags":64
       },
       "mute":false,
       "deaf":false
    },
    {
        "roles":[
           "848173029280055326"
        ],
        "nick":null,
        "avatar":null,
        "premium_since":null,
        "joined_at":"2021-05-29T12:15:32.907000+00:00",
        "is_pending":false,
        "pending":false,
        "user":{
           "id":"848088079562571797",
           "username":"E. Gadd",
           "avatar":"9992dc24217be555eae9dfe1c9960b0e",
           "discriminator":"6174",
           "public_flags":64
        },
        "mute":false,
        "deaf":false
     }
]
```

And here is what my php code looks like:

```
<?php
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$total = 0;
foreach ($data["roles"] as $value) {
    if($value["roles"]==848173029280055326){
        $total = $total+1;
    }
}
echo $total;
?>
```

I can't seem to get a total of how many times **848088079562571797** appears inside of the json file. I always seem to get this error

```
Warning: Undefined array key "roles" in C:\xampp\htdocs\filterjson.php on line 5

Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\filterjson.php on line 5
0
```

May I have some help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop should look something like:

```
foreach ($data as $value){...}
```

Also, as it looks like you might have multiple roles (you made an "array" in the json, by putting them in squared brackets), just iterate over all of them:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($value["roles"]); $i++){
    if($value["roles"][0]==848173029280055326){
        $total = $total+1;
    }
}
```

This should easily resolve your problem. I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The actual simplest way is converting the json to a string and then use substr_count.

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("data.json");
$role = '848173029280055326';
$count = substr_count($jsonData, $role)
```

$count will be the number of times it is in your json

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
foreach ($data["roles"] as $value) {
```

to

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
```

because your json structure is an array of objects